# Downgrade Ruby 2.1.5 to 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, downgrade

I have installed ruby 2.1.5 version and want to downgrade it to 1.9.3 to avoid "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle in windows". I have tried rmv function, but it is not working and also tell me how to remove older versions.

Comment: Simply uninstall 2.1.5 (like any other program or find the link in the start menu) and install 1.9.3 or better yet 2.2.2!?

Comment: That message is a totally ignorable warning by the way - it's not an error message and won't stop ruby working

Comment: bundle exec rake db:migrate command is not working

Comment: the following result is shown
C:\workspace\sample>bundle exec rake db:migrate
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

Comment: @rasevanth looks like there are more details, please edit the question and add more details (such as when that message occurs and what happens after that).

Comment: nothing it moves to the next line

Comment: like
C:\workspace\sample>bundle exec rake db:migrate                                 DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle                                                         DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle                        C:\workspace\sample>bundle exec rake db:migrate

Answer (score 1):

So what's the issue ? Does migration complete ? If you mind *just* for the warning about DL being deprecated, downgrading to already *[unsupported](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/02/23/support-for-ruby-1-9-3-has-ended/)* Ruby version sounds ridiculous.

This may be just quite unharmful notice for developers to start using newer C-extension interface, while functionality is kept unaffected.

Comment: migration does not complete,the browser does not show the result

Comment: @rasevanth "Browser" ?? Please look into logs after migration task, to see what really happened. If it is a standard Rails project, they should reside in `<project_root>/log` subdirectory - `development.log`, `production.log` etc. based on environment being run in.